# how to get pixel values(rgba) of image in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I am referring link below but  getting error at

```
unsigned char* pixels = [image rgbaPixels];
```

saying

> No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'rgbaPixels'

So, my question is **how can I get pixel values(rgba) of image in objective c**

Link reference

https://www.transpire.com/insights/blog/obtaining-luminosity-from-an-ios-camera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the error

> No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'rgbaPixels'

because `rgbaPixels` is the custom function, that the blogger written it himself.

You can create one yourself

First, create the **Category** of `UIImage`

**.h file**

```
@interface UIImage (ColorData)
- (unsigned char *)rgbaPixels;
@end
```

**.m file**

```
#import "UIImage+ColorData.h"

@implementation UIImage (ColorData)

- (unsigned char *)rgbaPixels {
    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    return rawData;
}

@end
```